# Why do jstree appear broken while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)  in all the pages of Smartwcm web application SDK. I found that every time a page is being loaded, the **jstree** plugin displays an incomplete state before it displays the correct view. I am attaching the screenshots of the two views below

I have the screenshots which will explain the issue better:

1. the jstree while the page is still loading

[image]

---

2. The jstree after the page load is complete

[image]

---

I use **jquery-1.11.2**, **Bootstrap v3.0.3** and **jsTree - v3.0.0-beta10**.

I am adding some part of the code **(code section for the tree node named Manage My Images )** that I use for the jstree, below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"
            onclick="location.href='${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/landing/'">
            <span class="iconImg"><img src="/layout/common/adminv3/img/left_img_2.png" alt="image"></span>Manage Contents<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse <#if cm.module == 'simplewebcontent'>in</#if>" >
        <div class="panel-body" id="jstreeSection">
            <div id="jstree1" class="demo">
                <ul>
                    <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-book" }' class="jstree-open">
                        My Contents
                        <ul>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-book" }' class="jstree-open">
                                Manage My Images
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" <#if cm.section == 'addimage'>, "selected" : true</#if> }'><a href="#" onclick="location.href='/module/simplewebcontent/uploaddocimagecontent?type=I'">Add Image</a></li>
                                    <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" <#if cm.section == 'listmyimages'>, "selected" : true</#if>}'><a href="#" onclick="location.href='/module/simplewebcontent/liststaticcontents?ownedby=me&type=I'">List My Images</a></li>                                            
                                </ul>
                            </li>       

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>                  

    </div>          

</div>
```

and the javascript function I for this jstree is:

```
$(function ()
{

    $('#jstree1').jstree();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is your JS files included, in the top or bottom part? Looks like your script has a 'ready' portion which executes as soon as the DOM is ready.  Since your script is going to change the page view (for the JS Tree), you want the JS loaded as early as possible so your page does not spend a long time redrawing itself in front of your users. Try including your JS Tree related Javascript in HTML head section.

Comment: Currently I am including the JS files at the bottom of the page. I have also tried loading the the JS files at top of the page and it did not help solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using v3.0.0-beta10 version. Have you tried updating JS tree to latest: 3.1.0?

Comment: I hav not tried updating the jstree version, but can that be causing this issue......anway I will try your suggestion...thanks